# Log messages for apps in release mode

Tags: android, ios, logging, xamarin

We have a team located remotely that are testing our Xamarin based IOS and Android app, in order to better diagnose certain issues that are occurring we wish to see log messages.

Is there any better solution besides having a GUI on the screen with a series of log messages and then exporting those logs?

Is there perhaps a native place in IOS and Android where certain log files can be viewed and then exported ?

Comment: You can use something like [crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics)

Comment: You want to read log messages (not only crash messages) from the native storage of the device which has installed your released app?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT that is correct, I am able to get exception data using Xamarin Insights however I want to obtain regular logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Bugfender](https://github.com/bugfender/BugfenderSDK-android-sample)

https://bugfender.com/

> Bugfender is a remote logger for iOS and Android applications. It stores logs created by your application and sends them to our server, creating a remote console where you can see logs in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are some better solutions available besides having a GUI who is printing the log on screen.

You can use the following ones:

- HockeyApp
- Visual Studio Mobile Center
- Flurry Analytics
- BugSense
- Crashlytics
- Bugfender as @pedro-simões mentioned

and many more with Xamarin support.